# Showing that $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n_+ : w\cdot x \le \alpha\}$ for $w, \alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am simply wondering how I would formally show (and write down) this?

I believe attempted work is preferred, so here is what I think (somewhat formally).

Let us call the set defined in the title $B$

For the fact that it is bounded, I think I can say something like: Consider
$y = (y_1,\cdots, y_n)$ whee $y_i = (0,0,\cdots, a_i,\cdots)$ where $w_i a_i = \alpha$, which exists since $w\in\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ (so all it's components are $>0$). Then $y$ is an upper bound for $B$ (because any $z$ that has a component $z_i$ of even $\epsilon >0$ greater than a $y_i$ will have a dot product $>\alpha$.

For bounded below... well... clearly it is bounded below by zero.

For showing that it is closed.. this is where I am having trouble. I think I can maybe say that any limit point $z$ must have either $w\cdot z =0$ or $w\cdot z = \alpha$ because if we are not in one of these cases, then either:

thee is $z \in B$ that is limit point but doesn't satisfy this: but then I can find a neighborhood, $U$ really close such that $z'\in U \implies 0<w\cdot z'<\alpha$ which implies that $U$ is a subset of $B$ (I would find this neighborhood by looking at $\epsilon = \alpha - w\cdot z$ and then considering the neighborhood that is the $\frac{\epsilon}{n}$ ball around $z$).

or
There is a $z\not \in B$ that is a limit point (and obviously doesn't satisfy this). But by similar construction I can find a neighborhood around $z$ that doesn't intersect with $B$.

Hence, $B$ contains all it's limit points.

Does the above seem okay? Or is there a more straightforward way to show the result?

Thanks.

Edit: I guess I should probably specify whether  mean compact in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n_+$. I don't think it matters (outside maybe consider bounds/limit that have negative coordinates, i.e. more work to do), but if it matters just assume we are referring to $\mathbb{R}^N_+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: the function

$$f:\Bbb R^n_{\ge 0}\to\Bbb R,\quad x\mapsto w\cdot x=\sum_{k=1}^n w_k x_k$$

with $w_k\in\Bbb R_{> 0},\forall k$ is continuous. If you show that the set $[0,\alpha]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$ then it preimage $f^{-1}([0,\alpha])=\{x\in\Bbb R^n_{\ge 0}:w\cdot x\le \alpha\}$ is closed.

Then you must show that $f^{-1}([0,\alpha])$ is bounded, i.e that exists some $r>0$ such that some open ball $\Bbb B(x,r)\supset f^{-1}([0,\alpha])$. Now apply the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty much what I was looking for. However, for bounded, I think I can say that it is bounded by $f^{-1}([0,\alpha + \epsilon])$ for $\epsilon >0$, but I'm not quite sure how to express this as an open ball. Specifically, any open ball I think would have parts outside of $\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$. Is that okay? (I think it is okay to show compactness in $\mathbb{R}$, but isn't it also compact in $\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$, in which case I'm not sure if I can use an open ball?) Also, the ball I had in mind is $B(\bf{0},\max_i{\frac{\alpha+\epsilon}{w_i}}))$. Does that seem okay?

Comment: If the open ball get parts "out" of $\Bbb R^n_{\ge 0}$ it is ok because, by definition, they are open balls of the induced topology on $\Bbb R^n_{\ge 0}$ from $\Bbb R^n$. About your ball: in this moment I dont know if this is ok, just be sure that all points of our sets belong to this ball, this probably is easy to prove.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user106860 instead of the ball above using $\max_i\frac1{w_i}$ you need instead $\min_i\frac1{w_i}$. Anyway Im not completely sure, check it.